# XNA and DarkBasic

Tags: xna

What are the advantages of each over the other and is one easier than the other to learn?

Answer (score 3):

Note: I develop with XNA and have never heard of DarkBasic until now.

XNA offers support for Xbox and Zune platforms and has a large community and is supported officially by Microsoft.

XNA documentation and tutorials are plentiful and many 3rd party sites and blogs exist around it.

XNA is in C# which I find much more intuitive as a programmer compared to VB.

After about 10 hours of reading and doing small tutorials for XNA I felt capable of coding nearly any type of game quickly and efficiently. I find the basic architecture very intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

DarkBasic is older, based in basic which is probably not a great idea for non-students, and costs money, though very little. XNA is .NET based, generally C# based, and can target some devices like XBox and Zune. Personally, I'd recommend XNA over DarkBasic because you get very solid tools (IDE, debugger) from Microsoft. They're about similarly hard to learn.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned elsewhere, XNA allows easy development for the Xbox 360 and Zune platforms in addition to Windows.  XNA also is built on top of C# whereas DarkBASIC seems to use a propriety BASIC-like language (as you would expect).

I'm not sure how crazy I am about the prospect of spending lots of time developing in a language of that sort, as I view my XNA projects as a way to sharpen my C#/.NET knowledge while learning the new XNA framework tools at the same time.  (But that's just personal preference, of course.)

Unless there's some major upside to using DarkBASIC that I haven't seen, I would be pretty comfortable saying that XNA has an advantage over DB in almost every way.

Answer (score 1):

As a beginner programmer, I've been learning DarkBASIC Pro on & off for the past year. I enjoy it and I wish I only started much earlier. I've got two sets of books to assist myself with DBpro;

"DarkBASIC Pro - Game Programming second edition" 
"Hands On DarkBASIC Pro" I & II
All of which I can recommend if you're just starting out.

Also, if you are looking at coding in DarkBASIC, you're best to grab one of the newer IDE's, the most popular ones being either Synergy Editor or CodeSurge. Coding in the old original IDE is almost impossible once you've tried these new free ones.

With that, I can't comment on the advantages from one package to the other. I suppose it would depend heavily on what it is you're trying to do. But I do enjoy using DB Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I've been teaching Game Development for C++ programmers with Dark GDK for a couple of years now and find it very fast to execute (because of DirectX 9) and very easy to program (if you are a C++ or C# programmer)

From
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DarkBASIC_Professional:

> Dark GDK and Dark GDK .NET
>
> Dark GDK is a software development kit for C++. It implements most of the commands available in DBPro as well as give the user lower level access to the API. Currently Microsoft Visual Studio 6 and Visual Studio .NET 2003 are supported but The Game Creators have stated that they are planning to support Dev-C++ in future versions, although they have not yet extended support to Dev-C++, and the plans may be dropped now that Visual C++ 2005 is supported.[citation needed]. Dark GDK's API is very similar to that of DarkBASIC Professional, such that code can be very easily ported between C++ code utilising Dark GDK and DarkBASIC Professional code.
>   The Dark GDK is now also available with Visual C++ 2008 Express. Dark GDK is free for personal use, however you must purchase a license if you plan on selling a game made with Dark GDK.
>   Dark GDK .NET was created for the same purpose, except it allows the user to create games using Visual C# .NET or Visual Basic .NET. Unlike Dark GDK, Dark GDK .NET is only available commerically and has no free version.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the main advantages of each system over the other are as follows:

1. **XNA allows you to develop for more target platforms, most notably the XBox 360 game console**.  DarkBasic's target platform is limited to Windows PC, whereas XNA can produce games for both Windows PC and the Xbox 360 (as well as the portable Zune device, which as far as I understand is not a very popular platform).
2. **It appears that DarkBasic allows for a greater degree of RAD (rapid application development) programming than XNA allows for.**  I partially base my assumption on viewing GameCreator's "The 3D Gamemaker" product, which certainly allows for RAD development (and actually, even no programming required!).  I realize that "The 3D Gamemaker" and DarkBasic are not identical products; however, Dark Game Studio (which includes DarkBasic) is foundationally engineered on the premise of "Build game content with specialised tools".
3. **XNA is in my opinion probably slightly superior as a development language.**  This does not affect the overall quality of the end product, but only the programmer and the development of the product.  XNA is designed to be a truly object-oriented language and is based on the .NET framework which enforces object oriented design.  As far as I know, DarkBasic does support object oriented practices with its SDK; however I do not know to what degree DarkBasic supports object oriented programming.  Having said that, nonetheless DarkBasic probably does support object oriented programming to an adequate, if not great, degree.

Answer (score -1):

Dark Basic is for hobbiests.  It's quick, easy, and effective.
XNA is for someone who has skills and time.
It's the classic Power vs. Effecincy.  Similar to Python vs. C++, one's quick, one's powerful.

Comment: Saying Dark Basic is for hobbyists and XNA isn't for hobbyists as well (among others) is an oversight. I'm not sure if you've used either or both, especially going into the power vs efficiency.

Comment: But C++ is quick *and* powerful!